# changing class of main <li> tag only

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following unorderered list code which displays the list below:

```
<ul>
  <li name="EMI7428"><ins class="jstree-icon2">&nbsp;</ins><a href="#"><ins class="jstree-icon2">&nbsp;</ins>organ</a>
  <ul>
  <li name="EMI7436"><ins class="jstree-icon2">&nbsp;</ins><a href="#"><ins class="jstree-icon2">&nbsp;</ins>sub organ1</a>
  <ul>
  <li name="EMI8217"><ins class="jstree-icon2">&nbsp;</ins><a href="#"><ins class="jstree-icon2">&nbsp;</ins>sub organ2</a>
  <ul> 
  <li name="EMI8224"><ins class="jstree-icon2">&nbsp;</ins><a href="#"><ins class="jstree-icon2">&nbsp;</ins>sub organ3</a>
  <ul>
  <li name="EMI7428"><ins class="jstree-icon2">&nbsp;</ins><a href="#"><ins class="jstree-icon2">&nbsp;</ins>sub organ4</a>
  </li></ul>
  </li></ul>
  </li></ul>
  </li></ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

>   organ
>     sub organ1
>       sub organ2
>         sub organ3
>           sub organ4

When user clicks on a button, I would like to change the class of the `<ins>` tag for a particular `<li>` tag to be changed.

I am using the code below to change the class  of the `<ins>` tag.

```
$j("li[name='"+emi_id+"'] ins").attr("class","jstree-icon2"); // set class to display new icon
```

It is working fine, except for the following error. if user selects the first `<li>` tag (EMI7428), all the `<ins>` tags inside that `<li>` tag (all the `<ins>` tags of the `<ul>` found inside that `<li>` tag) have their classes changed and this is not the behaviour i would like. 
I would like only the class of the ins tags belonging to an `<li>` tag with a particular name to be changed and i don't want the change to propagate to the inner `<ul>`.

I would really appreciate it if somebody could help me out with this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the selector you want is:

```
$j("li[name='"+emi_id+"'] > ins")
```

The `>` symbol selects all elements that are a *direct* descendent of the li and not subsiquent non-direct child elements.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look here : http://api.jquery.com/child-selector/

```
li[name='"+emi_id+"'] > ins
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to change the class of the direct <li> tag.

Comment: I got it, i had to add the code below also:  $j("li[name='"+emi_id+"'] > a ins").attr("class","jstree-icon2");